# Jquery : Select a specific class name among multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element which is annotated with 3 css classes `input-small JFilterInput Status`.
where class name varies except `input-small JFilterInput`.

I need to select varying class name using some `jquery` selector.

I tried

```
var selectedClassName = $(this).attr('class:not(.JFilterInput)');
```

But it didn't work. How to do this..??

Comment: what is `$(this)` here? if you could post more code to see the context of the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var selectedClassName = $.trim(this.className.replace(/\b(input-small|JFilterInput)\b/g, ''))
```

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn What I understood is the element can have 3 classes where 2 of them are fixed, the OP want the 3rd class name

Comment: Exactly Arun, You hit the bull's eye .... ;) many thanks..it worked like charm.... ;)